# Rails remote call not working in Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

The following link works fine in Chrome and Edge, but doesn't in Firefox and IE. Checking the network graph for both show that the request is not sent. Holding my mouse over the link in Chrome and Edge will show an underline under the text and the destination at the bottom of the page. Firefox and IE do not show these, so it appears that IE and Firefox do not recognize this as a link

```
<a data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/fetch_data?macaddress=ACB3131B6445&time=hour">Hour</a>
```

Link is generated with:

```
<%= link_to "Hour", fetch_data_path(time: "hour", macaddress: @macaddress.to_s), method: :post, :remote => true %>
```

Edit: Jquery version is the latest, 3.1.

application.js:

```
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Is `jquery_ujs` getting loaded? Check the network > js tab. Do you get any warnings or errors in console?

Comment: Yes it's being loaded and no error in the console.

Comment: Yes, basically jquery is required for this particular thing. Its build into rails, and jquery_ujs file takes care of it. & jquery_ujs depends on jquery, hence jquery is also needs to be loaded. You can refer this [link](http://sts10.github.io/blog/2014/04/12/data-remote-true/) for more info

Comment: Navigate to the page you have the link in. Open network tab, hit **refresh** in the same page. And then try the link, see if its working?

Comment: No it does not. Nothing generated in the network graph, and when I hover over link the hint in the bottom left does not show the destination.

Comment: I think you have to change version of jquery because i have same issue solved by jquery version change.

Comment: Can you add some more information like: jquery version, your application.js code.

Comment: Try inspecting the link in firefox and see what it points out in the elements pane.

Comment: The link tag that is generated is completely valid, but it is probably modified by the JavaScript code after the page is loaded. We should check what is going on there and try to find possible JS error. Please switch to "Console" tab in Firefox's inspector and then try to use the misbehaving link. The contents of the console may bring us closer to the solution.

If the console remains empty, we should check the click event listeners that are set on the link node. They are marked in the DOM tree with a tiny grey "ev" symbols. It would be useful to know what gets executed after click.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my laziness was the cause.

I initially made my buttons incorrectly such that they only worked if you clicked on the text of the link rather than the whole button working as a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
    <%= link_to "Day", fetch_data_path(time: "day", macaddress: @macaddress.to_s), method: :post, :remote => true %>
</button>
```

Finally decided that I should fix this and after recreating the link it worked fine in firefox:

```
<%= link_to fetch_data_path(time: "day", macaddress: @macaddress.to_s), method: :post, :remote => true do %>
    <div class="btn btn-default" type="button">Day</div>
<% end %>
```